# Bacth Apex class to update- below code is not working

Tags: apex, batch

I want to update all StageName='Perception Analysis' Opportunity every when i am created. I am getting

```
global class BatchApexUpdateOpptyStage implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{    
    string query;    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {        
        query='Select Id, Name,StageName From Opportunity'
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Opportunity> scope){
        system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@Execute+ scope');    
            for(Opportunity Oppty: scope)
                {                                          
                   system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@Update+ Oppty.StageName');  
                    if(Oppty.StageName=='Perception Analysis')
                    {
                        Oppty.Name= 'testkiller1'
                    }                    
                    update Oppty;
                }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}
    }
```

Comment: Whats not working? Besides a DML in a loop and the scope not being a List<sObject>

Comment: it's showing the error is that " unexpected token 'return'... what it's means

Comment: You do not have a ; after the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of little stuff wrong so will save you the trouble:

- Each line in `Apex` must end with `;`. You are missing this character after your query string.
- You have DML inside of loop. Simply update `scope` when done.
- The parameter from the `execute` method is of type `List<SObject>`, but your loop variable was of type `Opportunity`. Change your loop collection type to `List<Opportunity>` (simpler) or change your loop variable type to `SObject` (need to change code within loop).

  ```
  global class BatchApexUpdateOpptyStage implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{    

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
      String query='Select Id, Name,StageName From Opportunity';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }    

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope){
      system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@Execute+ scope');    
          for(Opportunity Oppty: (Opportunity[])scope)
              {                                          
                 system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@Update+ Oppty.StageName');  
                  if(Oppty.StageName=='Perception Analysis')
                  {
                      Oppty.Name= 'testkiller1';
                  }                    

              }

              update scope;
  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

  }
  }
  ```

Comment: So what exactly did go wrong? Should we run a diff to understand what you changed?

Comment: Its in my comment to the question. I will add them here

Comment: expecting semin-colon(  ; ) at line 16...

Comment: 1 question ?  what it means "(Opportunity[])scope)"

Comment: You have to cast to `List<Opportunity>` if you want your loop variable to be of type `Opportunity`.

Comment: Debug code is correct or not BatchApexUpdateOpptyStage up = new BatchApexUpdateOpptyStage(); 
Database.executeBatch(up,1);